# how can i find my system turn on and turn off timing

Tags: windows, linux

Is there is possibility to find my system turn on and turn off timings in last few days.
i want to know last booting time of my system, and who operated my system in last day...
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `last`and `uptime` in your terminal to achieve this.

last will show you who worked on your system and uptime for example will show you how long your system is running since its last boot.